Problems with Authorization for GitHub API
My code:
public class GitHubHeader {
  public static HttpHeaders getUserAgentHeader() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("User-Agent", "dopiotrko");
    headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer ghp_SEnZ1XFxx_rest_of_token_xxs3WbaMW");
    return headers;
  }
}

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", GitHubHeader.getUserAgentHeader());
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> exchange = rest.exchange(
          "https://api.github.com/users/" + user + "/repos",
          HttpMethod.GET,
          entity,
          String.class);

But still get

403 rate limit exceeded: "{"message":"API rate limit exceeded for
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit

I have tried "token" insetted of "Bearer" as well
